# Create a function in codeigniter that returns true if the input datetime is 2days ahead of current datetime, othewise false

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in codeigniter, im trying to create a function that accepts datetime input from a user. If the input is 2 or more days ahead of current datetime, it should return true, if not it should return false.

```
//my controller looks like this:
public function checkDateTimeInput(){
        $dateTimeInput = $this->input->post('dateTimeInput');
        if($dateTimeInput /*Greater than 2 days or more*/){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }



//in my view:
<?php echo form_open('schedules/checkDateTimeInput'); ?>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dateTimeInput">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) `today +2 day` to get the next 2 days :

```php
public function checkDateTimeInput(){
    $dateTimeInput =  new DateTime($this->input->post('dateTimeInput'));
    $next_days = new DateTime('today +2 day');
    if($dateTimeInput > $next_days) {  /*Greater than 2 days or more*/
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: anyways, thank for the idea, 
i have it now working.
instead of:
$next_days = new DateTime('now +2 day');
i used this:
$next_days = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days"));

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should be formatting the posted date first, and changed to using `today` parameter

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this in your controller, The below given code is for 12 hour format**

```
//my controller looks like this:
public function checkDateTimeInput() {
    // date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); // make sure you have set it to yours in config file
    $date1 =  date('Y-m-d h:i:sa', strtotime('+2 days'));
    $posted_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa', strtotime($this->input->post('dateTimeInput')));

    if($posted_date_time >= $date1){
        //return true;
        echo "True";
    }
    else {
        //return false;
        echo "False";
    }
}
```